# SSRS SharePoint Report Builder and Recurring events

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, recurrence

I'm using Report Builder SQL 2014 with a SharePoint list data connection to a calendar list. 
I'm trying to retrieve all items including the recurring items. I do not know how to write code and I have copied and pasted all of the possible options I found into the dataset query to try to retrieve the information that I'm looking for however I'm unable to get anything other than single items or parent items.
I'm unable to set up an XML data connection so any possible solutions that require that type of connection are not possible. I'm hoping that someone has something I could copy and paste into my data set query that would allow me to retrieve all events meeting the report parameters start date and end date. The events that I'm looking for will most likely always be in the past as we are looking to get a two-week history for each report.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint stores only a single item in the list for a recurring item, but stores the recurrence information in a field in each item named `RecurrenceData`.  I don't know if it is possible to parse this value using SSRS, but more details on the schema of that value is located here:  https://fatalfrenchy.wordpress.com/2010/07/16/sharepoint-recurrence-data-schema/

Comment: Thank you - I did find that exact information in my quest! What I need to know is how to adjust my dataset query to expand the recurrence. I have found several possibilities but I run into issues running the query where the tag is not valid (like DateRangesOverlap and Value Type with a closing of ValueType).